# If $x^2+x+1=0 $, then find the value of $(x^3+1/x^3)^3$?

Tags: polynomials

> If $x^2+x+1=0 $, then find the value of $(x^3+1/x^3)^3$

This thing doesn't make sense how should I use first identity to find the second one.

Answer (score 9):

$x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1) = 0$, so $x^3=1$. That's all you need.

Comment: $(x^3+1/x^3)^3$ expanding will get me $x^3 - 1$? So the 1st step is to expand all the terms?

Comment: You don't need to expand. Put $x^3 =1$ directly to $(x^3 + 1/x^3)^3.$

Comment: I am a little confused. Where do I get the $x^3 - 1$ from? Or where do I found out $x^3 = 1$

Comment: $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ is an identity. It equals to zero because $x^2 + x+1 = 0$ (given).

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+x+1=0 \to x+1/x=-1 \to (x+1/x)^3 = -1\to x^3 + 3(x+1/x) + 1/x^3 = -1\to x^3+1/x^3 = 2 \to (x^3+1/x^3)^3 = 2^3 = 8$

Comment: x+1/x=-1 is this some sort of identity or deduced from one

Comment: $x^2 + x + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow x(x + 1/x + 1)=0 \Rightarrow x + 1/x + 1 = 0.$

Comment: Is it an identity

Comment: It is not an identity. Back2Basic used what is given to deduce this result.

Answer (score 0):

***HINT:***  Use $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$ and also the fact that if $x^2+x+1=0$, then $x+\frac1x$=$-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The response of @TonyK is perfect and exemplary. Since some seem not to follow it, let me reinterpret it. By using Euclidean Division on $X^2+X+1$ and $X^3$, you get the *identity* $X^3=(X^2+X+1)(X-1) + 1$. This identity is still valid when any number is substituted for $X$. In particular, when you substitute that $x$ for which $x^2+x+1=0$. So $x^3=1$, and $1/x^3=1$.

Comment: maybe you wanted to write $x^2+x+1=0$ instead of $x^2+x+1=1$?

Comment: @Lubin I actually still have trouble understanding... But I must focus on my derivative problem set first. Thanks for providing additional insight!! I will come back as soon as they are completed.

Comment: @Galc127, or course, thanks for spotting the embarrassing sloppiness on my part.